# Help identifying a character from a picture

Tags: words, kanji

I've tried using handwriting identification and building it from radicals, but no luck. The closest I found was き and I’m not sure if it’s that character but the source text uses both き and this one, which leads me to think no.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it might help if you showed us the surrounding characters but that looks *exactly* like き to me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ki_(kana)

Answer (score 2):

That's a hiragana き or I'm an orangutan.